# Can't submit image file in site made with flask web services

Tags: python, flask

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dog or cat huh</title>
    <style>
        *{
            font-size: :30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <input id='input_image', type='file'/>
    <button id='submit_button'>Submit</button>
    <p style='font-weight: bold'>Predicions</p>
    <p>Dog <span id='Dog_prediction'></span></p>
    <p>Cat <span id='Cat_prediction'></span></p>
    <img id='selected_image' src=''/>

    <script href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let base64Image;
        $('#input_image').change(function(){
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e){
                let dataUrl = reader.result;
                $('#selected_image').attr('src', dataUrl);
                base64Image = dataUrl.replace("data:image/png;base64","")
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL($('#input_image')[0].files[0])
            $("#Dog_prediction").text("");
            $("#Cat_prediction").text("");
        });

        $('#submit_button').click(function(event){
            let message={
                image: base64Image
            }
            console.log(message);
            $.post('http://192.168.1.106:5000/predict', JSON.stringify(message), function(response){
                $("#Dog_prediction").text(response.prediction.dog.toFixed(6));
                $("#Cat_prediction").text(response.prediction.cat.toFixed(6));
                console.log(response);
            })
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import backend as k
import io
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_model():
    global model
    model = load_model('VGG_cats_and_dogs.h5')
    print('Model loaded!')

def preprocess(image, image_size):
    if image.mode != 'RGB':
        image = image.convert('RGB')
    image = image.resize(target_size)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    return image

get_model()
print('Model is loading.........')

@app.route('/predict', methods=["GET","POST"])
def predict():
    if request.method=='POST':
        message = request.get_json(force=True)
        encoded = message['image']
        decoded = base64.b64code(encoded)
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(encoded))
        processed_image = preprocess(image, target_size=(224, 224))

        prediction = model.predict(image).toList()
        response = {
                'predictions':{
                    'dog': prediction[0][0],
                    'cat': prediction[0][1]
                }
        }
        return jsonify(response)
    else:
        return render_template("predict.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm trying to create a web application using flask to classify images using VGG16. The website loads fine I can select the file but can't submit the image. After clicking the submit button, nothing happens. In the original tutorial GET was not added in methods but without it my website wouldn't load so I had to add the if else statement for POST and GET which loaded the website.
Anyone?
[image: image of page]

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is failing, check the developer console of your browser.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at predict:23
```

---

You weren't loading jQuery properly.

You need to do this:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

not this:

`<script href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Amended comment